# How to pass number to crypto-js hmac sha1 method?

Tags: javascript, react-native, cryptojs, hmacsha1

I have  different results in java and js code when using `HmacSha1` method. after spend time to searching, I found that maybe my message should passed as a number to `HmacSha1` method. so how to do this?
this is my code :

```
import Crypto from "crypto-js";

 Crypto.HmacSHA1(
   "26056085",
   Crypto.enc.Hex.parse("0899917B8146FFE4")
 );
```

so, how to send `"26056085"` as a number message? Also i know that this method parameters accepts string type.
maybe this [link](https://www.jokecamp.com/blog/examples-of-creating-base64-hashes-using-hmac-sha256-in-different-languages)
can help you for help me.

Comment: Can you please provide the output in java and javascript

Comment: in js  my result is : `E79B8A3926C18E7459AD029EF7F9424A42BBDBB2` and in java is : `ae88dd66cd58b91ade558629793c1f3346387b79`

Comment: Can you please try this Number("26056085") instead of "26056085"

Comment: I tried before, but is incorrect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more trying, we have to generate `HmacSha1` in native code (swift).
so we used react native bridge communication between `react native` and `swift`.
this [link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-ios.html#properties) can help you.